# Thunar can't access (samba) shares throught "Browse Network"

Tags: debian, samba, xfce, avahi, network-shares

x86_64 Debian Stretch kernel version is 4.7.8-1 with XFCE

I wasn't able to open shares (samba) with `Thunar` in Browse Network (`network:///`).
In location bar I could saw bad dns-sd names, when I tried to access shares. Names look like this:

> network:///dnssd-domain-tetris%2520-%2520SMB%255CsCIFS._smb._tcp

- where **tetris** is name of my server

So I guessed problem is in special characters (spaces etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched [dns-sd](http://www.dns-sd.org/) name is created by service [avahi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/avahi#Vsftpd). Then I just edit file on my server: `/etc/avahi/services/smb.service`
and replace string with single word (name) of my server. (Or you could use "%h" which automatically insert your server name)

**Before:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h - _SMB/CIFS</name>
  <service>
    <type>_smb._tcp</type>
    <port>445</port>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

**After:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">tetris_smb-cifs</name>
  <service>
    <type>_smb._tcp</type>
    <port>445</port>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

Now Thunar works fine.

Comment: Surely this won't work if you have multiple SMB instances on a network?